# Changing password in Django using AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views, django-authentication

I'm developing a website, and I already integrated the feature of **letting the user to change his/her password**. I'm using the built-in view in `django.contrib.auth`.

Now, **we need to do it using AJAX**. I mean, the idea is to send the request to the server without reloading the entire page. If the password was changed correctly, then I just need to show a message, and if not, the form with the errors of each field.

I could do it **creating a separate view** for that purpose, but I'm wondering **if there is an alternative**? I mean, the view should be pretty easy, but is already done in `django.contrib.auth`...

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to subclass existing django.contrib.auth views, but I think writing your own ajax-specific view is a better approach and it only takes a few lines of code anyway.

Here is what it may look like:

```
@login_required
def change_password(request):

    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            # extract new_password value from POST/JSON here, then

            user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("USER_NOT_FOUND")
        else
            user.set_password(new_password)
            user.save()

        return HttpResponse("OK")
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status = 400)
```

Comment: OP means user can only change his/her password. GET method here looks bad also.

Comment: @okm Sure. I was also refering to `change_password`, not `reset_password`. @BluesRockAddict thanks. In fact, I could easily copy and paste the code from the `password_change` view, and just modify the responses, but I was wondering if there is a way that doesn't involve copying and pasting the code. Thinking better, I don't really think there is `:(`

Comment: I mean why you need id here, isn't request.user enough? Your code allows logged-in user to modify others password, which sounds bad. Also, HTTP methods have their own implication, GET is not for such task.

Comment: Nope, this view will work just as well with POST (if you use $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',...}) in jQuery for example). What are the "implications" you're talking about?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506286/http-get-and-post . Yes, it works w/ POST method, by simply POSTing nothing to URL like '/change_password/1/secret_password'...

Comment: Wrong again. You might want to consider re-reading documentation on jQuery, especially on sending JSON data with jQuery.ajax method via HTTP POST.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to choose, I would also go with implementing a separate view for your purpose.

Ideally, if `django.contrib.auth` was re-implemented in class-based views, you would be able to reuse the logic of changing password and write your code only for the part that returns a response that is more appropriate for AJAX. But too bad we don't have the luxury of that, at least not for django 1.3 or prior.

But to answer your question, yes, there is an alternative (or hack I would call it) that enables you to reuse the view in `django.contrib.auth`. Assuming you are using **jQuery**, at submitting the change password form, you would make a AJAX POST request to the server and expect **html** in return (illustrated below). The returned html is the same as the one you would get when using non-AJAX POST.

```
  var post_url = $form.attr("action");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: post_url,
    data: $form.serialize()
  }).done(function(html) {
    // check the html and use that to determine what message to prompt back to your user
  });
```

Comment: Even if this post is quite old, could share with us how you did to implement password_change_view using Ajax?